# Previous adjacent sibling selector workaround?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two adjacent selectors that I would like to effect when hovering over the other. In the example below, the two selectors should effect the others CSS when hovered. This works perfectly when hovering `.a`, but not when hovering `.b`. I realize this is because the DOM is read in order, and therefore CSS selectors cannot work backwards.

However, is there a jQuery workaround (or any other suggestions) that can achieve this effect?

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynvswgxj/)

Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<figure>
    <div class="a">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="b">
        B
    </div>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
.a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.b {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}

.a:hover ~ .b {
    background: green;
}

.b:hover ~ .a { /* This one doesn't work */
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: you can try this, using jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/fLs6o3qo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no previous selector in css. One way is to implement it wiht jQuery like @Alex Char pointed out, and other way is with hover on parent, instead the actual items, with pure css like this:

```css
.a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
.b {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}

.parent{             /* ADDED */
    width: 100px;
}

.parent:hover > div:not(:hover) {   /* ADDED */
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<figure class='parent'>
    <div class="a">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="b">
        B
    </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you @1l13v, this is my preferred method for this instance. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't css previous element selector.

> ```
> .b:hover ~ .a { /* This one doesn't work */
>     background: green;
> }
> ```

[**General sibling combinator**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators):

> The general sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~)
>   character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
>   elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the
>   document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the
>   second one.

One solution is using jquery [**.prev()**](https://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```js
$(".b").hover(function() {
  //using prev selector and toggleClass
  $(this).prev().toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
.a:hover ~ .b {
  background: green;
}
.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
  <div class="a">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    B
  </div>
</figure>
```

**References**

[.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: Thanks @Alex_Char - This is great but in my current setup the pure css parent example below is more practical. I was open to using jQuery but now it doesn't seem necessary. Im sure this answer will be very useful for others though, so thank you.