# Changing property of an element on hover of another element after it

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I got two div's and I want to change the color of the first by hovering the second one. I found solutions when the "hovered " come before the objective that its css should be changed, what if the "hovered" come after? What could be done without javascript?

```css
.box, .box-2 {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.box-2:hover + .box {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to inverse the order **visually** and keep the order in the DOM so that you can still use the `+` selector.

Here is an example with flex:

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.box, .box-2 {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: blue;
  order:2; /* this will make box-2 goes after */
}

.box-2:hover + .box {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <div class="box-2"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

---

Some related question to get more ideas:

[Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

[Previous adjacent sibling selector workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946303/previous-adjacent-sibling-selector-workaround)

Answer (score 1):

While Temani's answer is a great technique, I have an alternative suggestion if you need this to work both ways, using the `:not()` selector, though it's a tad bit more hit-or-miss because of your margins.

If you check for the hover on the `.wrapper` element, you can then style your box when it isn't hovered, like so:

```
.wrapper:hover > .box:not(:hover) {
    background-color: green;
}
```